# Looking for a Package That Can Add AsciiDoc-like Callouts

Tags: code

I really love the "callout" functionality that can be added to source code listings in AsciiDoc https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/verbatim/callouts/. I was wondering if there is a LaTeX package that can do the same. I currently am using the 'minted' package for source code listings, and would like for it to be compatible with that package if possible.

Thanks

Comment: `minited` simply passes everything as-is to Pygmentize, so won't I think help here. Is using `listings` an option? It has the concept of leaving some char available for 'escape' so can allow some active code in otherwise verbatim material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out a way to it is to use the `pifont` and `color` packages in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{python}
import numpy as np

def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)
    M = None #to become the incidence matrix | \textcolor{black}{ \ding{182} } |
    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable

    #compute the bitwise xor matrix
    M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
    M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 

    for i in range(m-1):
        for j in range(i+1, m):
            [r,c] = np.where(M2 == M1[i,j])
            for k in range(len(r)):
                VT[(i)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(i)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + c[k]] = 1;

                if M is None:
                    M = np.copy(VT)
                else:
                    M = np.concatenate((M, VT), 1)

                VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)

    return M
\end{minted}

\ding{182} Here is have a comment

\end{document}
```